# How to debug MediaWiki's Database error?

Tags: mediawiki

How to debug MediaWiki's `Database error`?

> A database query error has occurred. This may indicate a bug in the software.

[image]

It would be good to have some more information about what's going on exactly.

https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:How_to_debug is not directly helpful

Answer (score 1):

Actually the MediaWiki Manual *is* useful.

This helped:

```
$wgDBerrorLog = '/var/log/mediawiki/dberror.log';
```

Just don't forget to create the directory and give permissions to `www-data` (or whichever user runs your PHP).